# Laravel 5 Merge an array

Tags: laravel-5, array-merge

I am trying to merge an array with an input from a form of a random string of numbers

In my form I have

```
<input type="text" name="purchase_order_number" id="purchase_order_number" value="{{ $purchase_order_number }}" />
```

And in the controller:

```
public function store(CandidateRequest $request)
{
    $candidateInput = Input::get('candidates');
    $purchaseOrderNumber = Input::get('purchase_order_number');

    foreach ($candidateInput as $candidate)
    {

        $data = array_merge($candidate, [$purchaseOrderNumber]);

        $candidate = Candidate::create($data);

        dd($data);
```

When I dd($data) it’s getting my purchase_order_number but as seen below but how can I assign it to that row in the table?

```
array:6 [▼
  "candidate_number" => "5645"
  "givennames" => "fgfgf"
  "familyname" => "dfgfg"
  "dob" => "01/01/2015"
  "uln" => "45565445"
  0 => "5874587"
]
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured this out with some help but the answer is to add:

```
$data = array_merge($candidate, ['purchase_order_number' => $purchaseOrderNumber]);
```

Thanks to everyone else who tried to help :)

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
$array = Arr::collapse([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

more: [laravel helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-collapse)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for taking the time and answering the question! Can you write more than your code and explain why it works?

Answer (score 4):

You could try this,

```
$data = array_merge($candidate, compact('purchaseOrderNumber'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this (the simplest I think) is to do a [**`union of arrays`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$candidate += ['purchase_order_number' => $purchaseOrderNumber];
```

> The ***`+`*** operator returns the ***`right-hand array`*** appended to the ***`left-hand array`***; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the ***`left-hand array`*** will be used, and the matching elements from the ***`right-hand array`*** will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $data = array_merge(['item'=>$item->toArray()], ['chef' => $chef->toArray()]);
```

Comment: While this might solve the problem, it is better to provide some explanation of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $firstArray->merge($secondArray);
```

Comment: `merge` method is part of the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class. So, to use it `$firstArray` must be a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = [];

foreach ($candidateInput as $candidate)
    array_push($data,$candidate);

 array_merge($data,$purchaseOrderNumber);

 $candidate = Candidate::create($data);

 dd($data);
```